# How to send query in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux

```
handleClick2(e, item, id) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  browserHistory.push({
    pathname: `/detail/${item}/${id}`,
    query: {crx:'handsome'},
    state: 'daf'
  })
}
```

How to send query in the way `browserHistory(react-router)`?

Comment: Are you looking for `this.context.router.push({ query: query });`?

Comment: bundle.js:41904 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
browserHistory.push({
        pathname:`/detail/${item}/${id}?crx=handsome`,
        state:'daf'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using a react-router `v1.0.x` then you should use `this.context.history.pushState()` and if you are using `>= v2.0.0` then make use of `this.context.router.push()`. This is how you use it

**this.context.history.pushState(...)**

```
// v1.0.x
    const SomeComponent = React.createClass({
      contextTypes: {
        history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
      },
      handleClick2(e,item,id){

       e.stopPropagation()
          this.context.history.pushState('daf', '`/detail/${item}/${id}`', {crx:'handsome'})

      }
    })
```

**this.context.router.push()**

```
   // >= v2.0.0
    const SomeComponent = React.createClass({
      contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
      },
      handleClick2(e,item,id){

       e.stopPropagation()
          this.context.router.push({
             pathname:`/detail/${item}/${id}`,
             query:{crx:'handsome'},
             state:'daf'
          })

      }
    })
```